# Can't integrate Firebase database in my app

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

im making an app, using Firebase Phone Authentication. It does work well, but now i've made a database for accounts (using firebase realtime database) and it stoped working. Here is my code and some screenshots. Hope it will help

```
private void signInWithCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();

                         String number = user.getPhoneNumber();

                        String uid = user.getUid();

                        HashMap<Object, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

                        hashMap.put("number", number);
                        hashMap.put("uid", uid);
                        hashMap.put("name", "");
                        hashMap.put("email", "");
                        hashMap.put("image", "");

                        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

                        DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("Users");
                        reference.child(uid).setValue(hashMap);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

                        startActivity(intent);


                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(VerifyPhoneActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

[screenshot of my databse rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YHUp.png)
[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWSzw.png)

[error section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uWwVD.png)

Comment: What do you mean through "stoped working"? If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: i added logcat, may it help?

Comment: There is nothing unusual there. Show us the error section. Change `verbose` to `error`.

Comment: one line only 

2019-09-24 15:55:07.454 30085-30085/? E/le.verificatio: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000

Comment: See the error section and add it to your question.

Comment: added error section, but it also looks  fine